# How to split a comma-seperated values into multiple columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
Data :
Teams
------------
India, Tamil Nadu, Chennai Super kings
```

Here Teams is a Column Name.

I want this output given below,

```
Team 1 |     Team 2    | Team 3
-------------------------------------------------------------
India      | Tamil Nadu | Chennai Super kings
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will it always be three?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)